# CSS div troubles (borders and images)

Tags: html, css, image

Situation's a bit of a long stoy so I won't bother.  Point being, I'm trying to place image links to different pages on specific places on top of a background image.  I have the background image, and I have the linked images appearing within the div.  The problem is now the images don't change no matter how I change their parameters.
Here's the HTML

```
<div class='links' id ='canvas'>
            <a id='anchor1' href ='index.html'><img class='one' src ="images/links/Alert-detail.png" ></a>
            <a id='anchor2' href ='index.html'><img class='two' src ="images/links/Command-detail.png" ></a>
            <a id='anchor3' href ='index.html'><img class='three' src ="images/links/floppy-detail.png" ></a>   
            <a id='anchor4' href ='index.html'><img class='four' src ="images/links/smiling-computer-sea-green.png" ></a>   
            <a id='anchor5' href ='index.html'><img class='five' src ="images/links/trash-detail.png" ></a> 
            <a id='anchor6' href ='index.html'><img class='six' src ="images/links/unhappy-computer-blue.png" ></a> 
            <a id='anchor7' href ='index.html'><img class='seven' src ="images/links/watch-detail.png" ></a>        
        </div>
```

Note I'm not having the links lead to anywhere until I get the positions right.

And the CSS for it

```
         #canvas{
    position:relative;
    height: 410px;
    width: 881px;
    outline: 2px solid red;
    background-image:url('../images/link layout.png');

    }
    .anchor1{ 
    position:absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
    outline: 2px solid green;
    z-index: 15;
        }
```

Comment: do you want those links to show up next to each other?

Comment: In your CSS, you reference a class `.anchor1`, which is not present on any of you `<a>`-tags - is that intentional??

Comment: maybe he meant `#` instead `.`

Comment: Yeah. You have in your HTML `id='anchor1'` but in your CSS you have `.`. `.` is class and `#` is id. Change your CSS to `#anchor1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to `.anchor1` which is a class, however you want to use `#anchor1` which would refer to an ID. I would suggest adding a class to all of the `<a>` tags which you apply the position, `outline` and `z-index` to, and using the `#anchor1`, `#anchor2` etc for the `left` and `top` attributes.